# Is there any fix for a fieldname that already has spaces in it?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, fields-attributes, text

I get it. I won't do it again. Is there any fix once it is already done? I would have preferred they gave me an error when I brought the file in.

The data came from a county database where the .csv file had spaces in its title (also had an and in it). The field attributes created based on that .csv without any manipulations. The table was later joined to a shapefile to match attributes.

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?

Comment: Just do table to table, csv to dbf. Arcgis will create legit fields.

Comment: I was using ArcGIS pro. I solved I got python to eliminate the spaces and rewrite the data as a .csv file. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can 'fix' it unless the data is in a file or enterprise geodatabase. You could recreate your feature class (with the correct field names) in a new geodatabase and load your existing data into that using field mapping. Then re-do your joins.

Comment: ArcGIS *can't* create field names with spaces in FGDB or a database (or shapefile, for that matter). It uses *aliases* before actual names in display, and aliases *can* have spaces.

Comment: Found out the hard way. I do believe I edited the data in python to match everything. That is not hard for me while the rest of the software is.